# Unsure vs not sure

Tags: adjective-phrases

> We are ***unsure*** of what is requested?
>
> We are ***not sure*** of what is requested?

Which one should should be used and why? Is there any difference between the two?

TIA

Comment: They're both fine, and mean the same, but note that ***not sure*** is still [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsure%2Cnot+sure&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunsure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20sure%3B%2Cc0). There are some other differences in idiomatic usage - only the one-word form really works as an adjective before a noun *(an unsure foundation)*, and it's more acceptable to use the two-word form without a preposition *(of, about)*, for example.  But these subtle points don't matter much anyway.

Comment: You can't, because it's a *comment,* not an *answer*. I've just briefly mentioned a couple of usage differences that come to mind, but someone else will need to dig into the matter more carefully to decide whether either of those are matters of grammatical correctness (as opposed to mere idiomatic preference), and whether there are any more significant differences.

Comment: We are unsure/not sure of what is being requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> unsure

is the general, all purpose way of saying "not certain", it encompasses the varying degrees of

> not sure
>
> not so sure
>   not too sure
>   not very sure
>   somewhat sure